# Merge objects with the same id but sum values of the objects

Tags: javascript, group-by, reduce

I want to reduce my array of objects by comparing previous and current object from the array, if the id of previous object is different then current object, then I write the previous object to my result list and override it with the current object else I sum the values of both objects. In the end it should be a reduced array, no duplicates.

I have data like this:

```
[{
    Clicks: 210,
    Company: "A",
    _id: { CompanyID: 5 }
},
{
    Clicks: 35,
    Company: "C",
    _id: { CompanyID: 3 }
},
{
    Clicks: 15,
    Company: "B",
    _id: { CompanyID: 2 }
},
{
    Clicks: 13,
    Company: "A",
    _id: { CompanyID: 5 }
}]
```

And want to reduce it to this form:

```
[{
    Clicks: 223,
    Company: "A",
    _id: { CompanyID: 5 }
},
{
    Clicks: 35,
    Company: "C",
    _id: { CompanyID: 3 }
},
{
    Clicks: 15,
    Company: "B",
    _id: { CompanyID: 2 }
}]
```

Here is my not correctly working solution so far:

```
$scope.reduce = function () {
    var result = [];
    var prev = null;

    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (value, key) {
        if (prev != null) {
            if (prev._id.CompanyID != value._id.CompanyID) {
                result.push(prev);
                prev = value;
            } else {
                prev.Clicks += value.Clicks;
            }
        } else {
            prev = value;
        }
    });
}
```

My result looks good, it reduce all duplicates but it does not sum the values of objects with the same ids, it just overrides the ids with the last object.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `thisArg` parameter in `forEach` loop and pass a empty object to store values.

```js
var data = [{"Clicks":210,"Company":"A","_id":{"CompanyID":5}},{"Clicks":35,"Company":"C","_id":{"CompanyID":3}},{"Clicks":15,"Company":"B","_id":{"CompanyID":2}},{"Clicks":13,"Company":"A","_id":{"CompanyID":5}}];
var result = [];

data.forEach(function(obj) {
  var id = obj._id.CompanyID
  if(!this[id]) result.push(this[id] = obj);
  else this[id].Clicks += obj.Clicks;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I actually wanted to know what my mistake was. I already found out what i did wrong, i have logic error, because i reference to my first object instead of doing a deep copy. And your code is somewhat irritating by using the keyword this. I think it is not good to use this in javascript, specially here. :)

Comment: `I think it is not good to use this in javascript` why is that?

Comment: In your example "this" is irritating, but it works fine, but not a good design from my point. It is not clear what "this" actually is. So for me and a lot of other developer will agree that "this" can be confusing ("this" in object scope or object's function scope?) and bring inconsistent behavior. Here is how i changed your code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pt8e6op6/)

Answer (score 4):

For a version with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you could use a hash table as reference to the same company with a closure over the hash table.

```js
var data = [{ Clicks: 210, Company: "A", _id: { CompanyID: 5 } }, { Clicks: 35, Company: "C", _id: { CompanyID: 3 } }, { Clicks: 15, Company: "B", _id: { CompanyID: 2 } }, { Clicks: 13, Company: "A", _id: { CompanyID: 5 } }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var key = a._id.CompanyID;
            if (!hash[key]) {
                hash[key] = { Clicks: 0, Company: a.Company, _id: a._id };
                r.push(hash[key]);
            }
            hash[key].Clicks += a.Clicks;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```